# Cómo alinear la linea dibujada con canvas con el div padre en su altura y ancho además de alinearla con porcentajes

Tags: javascript

Me interesa alinear la linea dibujada con canvas con el div padre, es decir el *troke* ya que como lo tengo la linea dibujada con canvas se deforma y no se complementa con el *troke-background*... La etiqueta canvas si se encuentra con ancho y el alto al 100% pero la linea no, además me interesa mover la linea con porcentajes, por ejemplo la variable *aFinal* está en 359 si la disminuyo va moviendose la linea hacia atrás y si aumento el número la linea debería completarse pero al contrario vuelve como a empezar. me interesa completarla y disminuirla con porcentajes, es decir 50%, 60%, 70% etc...

```js
var elCanvas = document.getElementById("lienzo");
        if (elCanvas && elCanvas.getContext) {
        var context = elCanvas.getContext("2d");
            if (context) {
                    var X = elCanvas.width/2;   
                    var Y = 80;
                    var r = 50;
                    var aPartida = (Math.PI / 1) * 320;
                    var aFinal =  (Math.PI / 180) * 359; // si disminuyo el 359 va acortandose la linea y si lo pongo en 360 se corta toda y no se "completa" como deberia ser
                    context.strokeStyle = "orange";
                    context.lineWidth = 20;
                    context.arc(X,Y,r,aPartida,aFinal,false);
                    context.stroke();
            }
        }
```

```css
.troke{
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
/*background-color: #ddd;*/
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.troke-background{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.troke-circle{
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
font-size: 25px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#lienzo{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="troke">

<canvas id="lienzo"></canvas>

<span class="troke-background"></span>

<span class="troke-circle">50%</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres lograr lo puedes hacer solo con CSS. En todo caso aquí tienes una posible solución usando el canvas:

```js
function calcEndByPercent(value) {
  // con esta regla de 3 calculas el ángulo final que rellena el círculo.
  // la circunferencia completa corresponde a 2 veces el numero PI (PI * 2)
  return value * Math.PI * 2 / 100;
}

function drawArc(value) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('lienzo');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // el arco se dibuja desde el centro, asi que aqui calculo esos valores:
  var halfX = canvas.width / 2;
  var halfY = canvas.height / 2;
  var strokeWidth = 20;
  // este es el origen del arco
  var x = halfX;
  var y = halfY;
  // el radio es la mitad del espacio menos el borde
  var radius = halfX - (strokeWidth / 2);
  // el ángulo inicial es Math.PI * 1.5 para que se comience a dibujar desde arriba
  // más no desde la derecha, si quieres cambiar esa posición solo debes 
  // modificar este valor entre 0 y (Math.PI * 2)
  var start = Math.PI * 1.5;
  // el angulo final se calcula sumando el angulo inicial más el porcentaje a rellenar
  var end = start + calcEndByPercent(value);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
  ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, start, end, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// esto solo es un input para probar la solución con un slider:
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var span = document.querySelector('.troke-circle');
span.textContent = input.value + '%';
// aqui se dibuja el arco pasando un valor entre 0 y 100
drawArc(input.value);

input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  span.textContent = value + '%';
  drawArc(input.value);
});
```

```css
/* agrega box-sizing: border-box para acomodar los elementos más fácilmente */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.troke{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.troke-circle{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* aqui creo el borde gris con css */
  border: 20px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#lienzo{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="troke">
  <!--
  establece un width y un height fijo en el canvas
  para evitar la distorsión, trata de evitar usar porcentajes.
  -->
  <canvas id="lienzo" width="150" height="150"></canvas>

  <!--
  si este background solo lo usas para formar un borde mejor eliminalo.
  aqui lo quito para formar el borde con CSS
  -->
  <!-- <div class="troke-background"></div> -->
  
  <span class="troke-circle"></span>

</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="25" />
```

Comment: Super bien explicado! Muchas gracias .